# Google Maps Geocoding APi not returning lat and long

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I'm utilizing the Geocoding API for converting and address to latitude and longitude coordinate values. I do receive results but the **lat** and **long** are empty. Other SO posts mention the Geocoder requests are asynchronous and Google just doesn't return the data fast enough. I'm not understanding how to fix this for my code if that is the problem.

```
var coords = [];
var address = '1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500';
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function( results, status ) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            coords[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            coords[1] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        }
        else {
            coords = 'Could not retrieve coordinates for: ' + address;
        }
    });
return coords;
```

Even if I use a well-known address I still get no lat or long.

**Results object:**

[image]

Is this really the problem or is there something wrong with the code I'm using? How can I fix this?

Comment: You can't return anything from an asynchronous callback function, you need to use the data there when/where it exists

Comment: Then what's the point of this documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

It mentions everything that is returned, including the geometry: {location: LatLng}... which is what I need.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a legitimate question. If you don't understand the issue or the documentation then ask a question. This is a public API and others have had issues with it which have not been addressed properly.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate question: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).  The lat/lng **are** returned (if the result is "OK"), they are just returned in the callback function **after** the value of `coords` is returned to the calling function.

Comment: Good link but that's what I was referring to. It sounds like it may be an async issue but I don't understand how to fix that. How does passing the results to another function give Google more time to respond with the full info requested? I can't imagine I am the only dev to ever come across this problem. There's just no info online with examples on a possible fix.

Comment: One option (which is described in the linked question) is a promise.

Comment: actually, you're right. I'm stuck using only certain methods, however. I can't implement jQuery, for example or something more suitable like promises. I'm looking at https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then use the asynchronous callback in the manner for which it was created (use the data in the callback function, when/where it is available, don't try to return it).

Answer (score 4):

this question was asked a long time ago but your code gave me hint to solve my problem.
The response returned from API call are only function lat & function lgt, that's why there are no coordinates. You have to call the functions as specified in the question

```js
coords[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
coords[1] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

if you console.log(coords), you can see the result.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great solution as well. Note: doesn't matter how long ago questions were posted. I am always grateful for answers/suggestions/ideas. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using this to solve the issue:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open( 'GET', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address, false);
request.send( null );
```

Though, I had to set false in order to keep the request synchronous. Seems this is/will be deprecated but for my purposes it should be fine. I can now parse through the json by doing the following:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open( 'GET', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address, false);
request.send( null );
```

This is fine I think. Just wish the Geocoder documentation made note of the asynchronous issues and provided better solutions.

Comment: This is not a good idea, you should call a (new) function at the end of the anonymous function there coords gets values.

Comment: If you have a code sample to share please do so to prove your point. The above worked just fine since this isn't a codebase open to anyone except for this internal project. We've documented the limitation and workaround. So yes, it was a good idea so that we could move forward.

Comment: This one does a few things with geocoding results: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/